# Better way to write deep maps in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, mapping

I am parsing a text file that contains lines of numbers.  I want to turn them into `[[[Int]]]`. (A list of cells inside of a list of rows inside of a list of boards.)

*sudoku.txt*

```
530070000
600195000
098000060
800060003
400803001
700020006
060000280
000419005
000080079

400700500
300800001
700900008
060030010
090070050
080010790
002006900
005000030
000004200
...
```

*main.hs*

```
parseTextExample :: IO ()
parseTextExample = do
  handle <- openFile "sudoku.txt" ReadMode
  contents <- hGetContents handle
  let splitBoards = splitWhen (== "") $ lines contents
  let sudokus = map (\board -> map (\row -> map (\char -> read [char] :: Int) row) board) splitBoards
  print sudokus
  hClose handle
```

`splitBoards` yields `[[String]]` and I want to use `sudokus` to yield `[[[Int]]]`. That requires a deep mapping that looks awful:

`map (\board -> map (\row -> map (\char -> read [char] :: Int) row) board) splitBoards`

Is there a more Haskellian way to write the `sudokus` function?

---

For reference:

```
> print splitBoards
>[["530070000","600195000","098000060","800060003","400803001","700020006","060000280","000419005","000080079"],["400700500","300800001","700900008","060030010","090070050","080010790","002006900","005000030","000004200"]]
```

```
> print sudokus
>
[[[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],[6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],[0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],[8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],[4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],[7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],[0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],[0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]],[[4,0,0,7,0,0,5,0,0],[3,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,1],[7,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,8],[0,6,0,0,3,0,0,1,0],[0,9,0,0,7,0,0,5,0],[0,8,0,0,1,0,7,9,0],[0,0,2,0,0,6,9,0,0],[0,0,5,0,0,0,0,3,0],[0,0,0,0,0,4,2,0,0]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap a value in a list by making use of [**`pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure), hence we can write the `\char -> read [char]`, as `read . pure`.

Next we can write the `\row -> map (read . pure) row` lambda expression as `map (read . pure)`. So that means that we can rewrite the line to:

```
let sudokus = map (map (map (read . pure))) splitBoards :: [[[Int]]]
```

or we can avoid these brackets with:

```
let sudokus = (map . map . map) (read . pure) splitBoards :: [[[Int]]]
```

Here it thus means that the `(read . pure)` is the mapping function of the "innermost" `map`.